# What is the general procedure for determing a parity check matrix given n, k, q, and d (not from generator matrix)?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, coding-theory

Is there a generic procedure for finding the parity check matrix in a linear code of $[n, k]$ over a finite field $F_q$ with a minimum weight of $d$? I am given $n$, $k$, $q$, and $d$, but I don't know the procedure for finding the parity check matrix from that. I understand how to determine the parity check matrix from the generator matrix but I'm not too sure about how to determine the parity check matrix directly from n, k, q, and d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a parity check matrix of a linear code $C\subseteq \mathbb{F}^n$ is simply a generator matrix for the dual code

$$C^\perp=\{x\in \mathbb{F}^n \,|\, \forall y\in C : \langle x, y\rangle =0\},$$

where

$$\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle : \mathbb{F}^n\times \mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{F},$$
$$\bigl((x_1,\dots,x_n),(y_1,\dots,y_n)\bigr)\mapsto \sum_{j=1}^n x_jy_j.$$

So what you can do is find a basis of $C^\perp$ and from that construct a generator matrix for $C^\perp$, which in turn will be a parity check matrix for $C$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :D. I understand now finding the basis of the orthogonal complement to form the parity check matrix but I'm confused as to how to know what C (a subspace of $F_{q}^{n}$) is to begin with. I'm not provided anything else other than n, k, q, and d.

Comment: So these give you different information about what properties the parity check matrix $H$ must have. For example, it can be shown the the separation $d$ is the number such that $H$ has $d$ columns which are linearly dependent, and all choices of $d-1$ columns are linearly independent. Furthermore from $n$ and $k$ we can get that $H$ must be a $(n-k)\times n$ matrix. Finally, $q$ tells you how many elements there are in the field which your matrix is over.